# Using FMDB with Multiple View Controllers in IOS

Tags: ios, sqlite, fmdb

I have an iOS app structured more or less like so:

```
Controller1/View1
  Controller2/View2
    Controller3/View3
    Controller4/View4
```

Is it ok to instantiate a FMDatabase for each of the controllers, even if those databases all point to the same path? Or do I need to share a single FMDatabase instance across the classes?

[FMDatabase locked, best practice for usage within class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23405119/fmdatabase-locked-best-practice-for-usage-within-class) suggests using a queue, but is that strictly necessary or desired if everything is on the same thread?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a single `FMDatabaseQueue` across your application as long as you have a single sqlite db. It takes care of access from multiple threads as well.